# VBA delete entire row based on duplicate criteria

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, rows

I am very new and my knowledge on VBA is BASIC. I tried the following code to color the duplicate values of row B and then delete the entire row of the duplicated values.
My range would start in cell B4. This code works to color but it wont delete anything.
Could someone please help me? thanks!

```
Sub ShowandDeleteDuplicateRows()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Range("B4", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 2)`, because `Cells(i, 3)` is column C. Though i don't see why you would color a cell, only to delete it immediately afterwards.

Comment: true haha thank you